# Evaluating simple geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a simple closed form for $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{2^{k-1}}$ if we know that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k = 1$, with $a_k \ge 0$ for all $k$? Intuitively, this seems like it'd be a little below one, and it feels "simple" enough that there must be a way to evaluate it directly, but it's not obvious to me. If we can't evaluate it symbolically, my ultimate goal is to maximize that sum with that constraint, so any ideas on how to go about doing that would be appreciated, too.

Comment: That's not necessarily a geometric series.  Are you requiring $a_k\ge0$?  If not, consider $a_1=100$, $a_2=-99$, and $a_k=0$ for $k>2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, they are non-negative, added to question.

Comment: The maximal value is equal $1$ and is attained for $a_1=1$ and $a_k=0,$  $k\ge 2.$ It follows from a simple estimate $\sum a_kb_k\le \sup b_k\sum a_k.$

Comment: Another special case: With $a_k=1/2^k$ we obtain a sum $2/3.$ Due to the rearrangement inequality, this is the lowest value for any "permutation" of these $a_k.$